# Change Proxy Connection .NET

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

I would change proxy connection with My Winform Applcation 4.0 .NET C#

I googled and i found some articles but all of them change the LAN proxy.

I want Change proxy of my connection like this one [Example](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/44930/)

Someone has a snipped code that help me to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe It Help you:http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/articles/CSharpCodeToMaintainVPNConnectionProgramatically.aspx

Comment: Can you post the code you currently use to setup/choose the proxy

Comment: I didnt find any working code at the moment. Here there is a code but it change Lan Proxy http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/19517edf-8348-438a-a3da-5fbe7a46b61a